# Convert flat module to eav module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, eav

I have a flat module on my site, which doesnt have store view switcher on add/edit page. I want to enable store view switcher on these pages so i tried to add a field using tabs ( admin html ) but it is not working. This module was created with UMC ( ultimate module creator )

Is there a way to enable store view switcher for collections and convert flat module to eav module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to rebuild the module again.
I hope you still have the xml file generated by the UMC.
you can edit the module, and change for your entities the type from `Flat` to `EAV` and regenerated it again.
But first you have to uninstall your current module. Use the uninnstall generated file to cleanup your database and remove all files and folders of the module.
But this will make you lose all the data you have so far.

Comment: I didnt created it before so from where I can get that xml file ?

Comment: what do you mean you haven't created before? Where did you get it then? Anyway, you can build it again even if you don't have the initial generated XML file. You can follow the instructions [in the documentation](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki). It should take you a few minutes.

Comment: I mean I didnt created but some other guy did so I am not sure about logic of module. So i can try with xml file if you can tell me where i can get it .

Comment: it should be in `var/modulecreator/package`. But if you still have the umc installed it should appear in the list of created modules.

Comment: My bad luck, its on production and I dont have xml file in there. Will check with login and create it again.  Thank @Marius, it was quite a lot info for beginner